# NHibernate Formula Uses Wrong Prefix

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following model:

```
public class Transaction {
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

The *TotalAmount* property is mapped as a formula like so:

```
Map(x => x.TotalAmount).Formula("Amount + Tax");
```

I then have two derived types (table-per-type):

```
public class EventTransaction : Transaction {
}

public class ProductTransaction : Transaction {
    public virtual Delivery { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I do the following query:

```
var transactions = session.Query<Transaction>().ToList();
```

The query executes successfully but ideally I'd like the TotalAmount against the product transaction to include the Delivery cost. Therefore in the product mapping class I overwrote the TotalAmount like so:

```
Map(x => x.TotalAmount).Formula("Amount + Tax + Delivery");
```

However this didn't work as the generated SQL assumes the Amount and Tax fields are within the product transactions table and prefixes the fields with the wrong alias.

I tried hard coding it with the correct alias from the generated SQL. However whilst this worked for this query, I have found that the alias used is not always the same with alternative queries and subsequently threw an error.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks

Comment: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-686 and https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas are basically raw SQL statements (which will be processed to add aliases), so you can't access inherited properties etc. But you can write a SQL subselect that gives you what you need.

```
(SELECT TOP 1 pt.Delivery + t.Tax + t.Amount 
FROM ProductTransaction pt 
INNER JOIN Transaction t ON pt.Id=t.Id 
WHERE pt.Id=Id)
```

Comment: Thanks this does the job. It would be neat in the future if you could specify the alias a table uses and then the solution would've been much simpler.